# Linux terminal emulator with frequent, recent, and bookmarked commands/directories

Tags: linux, terminal, terminal-emulator

I am looking for a terminal emulator where I don't have to tap the up key a million times to see the old and frequent commands.

I want to be able to bookmark common commands and directories, as well as see a list of frequent and recent ones.

And yes, I am aware of aliases, but I'm looking for a middle ground.

Comment: There is an even better solution but it doesn't use anything you've asked for. If you replace your shell with [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) then you will have a history that is easy to search. You just begin typing and, instead of tabbing to auto complete, you use the up\down arrows to search your history: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97844/46040

Comment: @krowe does it have a gui as well, or do I just run it in gnome-terminal?  I was hoping for some nice gui menues with recent and frequent commands...

Comment: No GUI, but tons of new functionality for the command line (which is better since that means that you don't need to take your hand off the keyboard to work).

Comment: bash: CTRL-R and typing will search in your history. Up/down arrows will allow browsing the history... an alias might be `alias pydir=cd $USER/bin/python` (a bookmark). http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html - will tell more (ehh... RTFM that is).

Answer (score 1):

With the suggestion from @krowe about zsh, and some research, I think I have settled on Oh My Zsh in Terminator using the latter's Custom Commands plugin.